# Mysql and excel csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysql-error-1267

i have a php script that has to compare some words in a csv file to a mysql table element. The problem is that apparently the csv file is'nt created in the correct codification.

The first error is this:
***SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'***

Now when i use `utf_encode` on the variable, the error goes away but it didnt find my variable int the mysql database.

To be clear, i have several accented words in my csv file, and i can´t change thhis.

i'm using **latin1** charset and **latin1_general_ci** collation in my DB.

Another observation is that i'm using thw following code to get information in the file:

```
if (($handle = @fopen("../arquivos/atualização/$name", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
```

Can i somehow convert my csv file in php without losing the accents? or convert my db tables?

Note: in notepad++ my CSV file is in ANSI codification, and when i convert it to utf the accents turn into strange characters.